# How can I reduce score of document if the document doesn't have a certain field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an existing query and I wanna modify it to reduce score of document if the document doesn't have a certain field.

How can I do it?

I try to reduce score of the document

Comment: can you please provide an example

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boosting Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-boosting-query.html) of Elasticsearch for reducing score of document based on specific condition:

Below are test documents:

```json
POST querycheck/_doc
{
  "name":"Sagar Patel"
}

POST querycheck/_doc
{
  "name": "Sagar Patel",
  "city": "Surat"
}
```

Below is result with simple match query for `sagar` which return same score for both the documents:

```json
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.18232156,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "querycheck",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hhmy9H8BhjVE4xoSgmhK",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Sagar Patel",
          "city" : "Surat"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "querycheck",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hxmy9H8BhjVE4xoSkWjU",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Sagar Patel"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Below is boosting query**:

```json
POST querycheck/_search
{
  "query": {
    "boosting": {
      "positive": {
        "match": {
          "name": "sagar"
        }
      },
      "negative": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "city"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "negative_boost": 0.2
    }
  }
}
```

**Result with diffrent score** (document without `city` field coming with low score):

```json
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.18232156,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "querycheck",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hhmy9H8BhjVE4xoSgmhK",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Sagar Patel",
          "city" : "Surat"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "querycheck",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "hxmy9H8BhjVE4xoSkWjU",
        "_score" : 0.036464315,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Sagar Patel"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```